# Can't change background color of Theme.Holo.Light action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I want to change colorPrimary of Theme.Holo.Light, but nothing changes.

```
<resources>

    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="whitegrey">#FFF2F2F2</color>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#FF0F91CD</color>
    <color name="holo_light_primary">#FF0F91CD</color>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/holo_light_primary</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And I am using custom theme's name in AndroidManisfesto as well. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, you're using your custom theme, and you're ignoring AppTheme, which holds the required change. Just move this line:

```
 <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/holo_light_primary</item>
```

to your custom theme element.

Comment: AppTheme is my custom theme.